# Delete Rails model and its associations in one action? NEWBIE question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, model-associations

I have a really simple association with the Devise user object where each user has one Profile (with more application specific stuff...)  I am having no issues creating the User object and accessing the user and its profile object. i.e., 
    @user.profile

However, I'm having an issues when I try to delete the profile object - I'd assume that when I delete the User object, it would also delete each associated object.  The association in my User object is like so 
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile, :allow_destroy => true

The has_one and belongs_to associations are set on both the User and Profile objects.  Maybe the issues is in Devise code - I'm stumped.  An idea what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify `:dependent` on the association:

```
has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy
```

Look [Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for more information.